# Como forçar rerenderização de um component com ionic/angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Preciso esconder um componente da interface após o usuário "excluir" ele. Não é de fato excluído do banco de dados, apenas é enviado uma propriedade `hidden_to_user` como booleano para o back através de um método `POST`e no preview eu recebo a prop como `true`.
No html eu coloquei um `display: none`caso `hidden_to_user`seja true, mas essa re renderização só acontece quando atualizo o app ou troco de rota e retorno para esta.
Estou apenas realizando manutenção de um projeto em ionic, não sei quase nada de angular. Existe algum método para forçar re renderização? Ou que fique ouvindo o componente e renderize novamente quando algo mudar. Penso em algo parecido com o Hook `useEffect`do React Js

OBS: projeto está usando o Angular 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso, você pode usar o `Angular` [Change Detection](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef), veja na documentação. Além disso, você também encontra alguns tutoriais online com exemplos em português.